# How to get an NTFS file's total size (including security and ADS)?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I'm having difficulties to find a way (if there is any) to get the total file size of a windows (NTFS) file.
What I'm trying to get is the size of the file including alternate data streams and security info ; default size only refers to the main stream (which contains the "real" data used by our applications).
I know I could get it calling BackupRead() and see how much I can read, but my need is to know it *before* I perform any operation on this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [FindFirstStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163677.aspx) where you're looking for?

Or [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2008/07/03/ntfs-misreports-free-space.aspx)?

Comment: I feared that  FindFirstStream/FindNextStream would be slow, seeking in the whole file to find streams, but I tried and it seems to work well and be quick. Thanks a lot!